# C++ Compress string using zlib, naming of document

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib

I'm using zlib to compress a stream of txt to a gz gzip file, and it's working well. However, it seems to name the file inside the gzip, exactly the same as my gz name.

I'm wondering is there any way to change the naming of the file that's been compressed?

I would rather it name like the following:

/myfile.gz/myfile

Where myfile is the document that's inside of the compressed gzip file, and myfile.gz is the gzipped file itself.

Is there any way to control these namings?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're saying is that when you decompress `whatever.gz`, you get a file named `whatever` in the current directory. That is the default behavior of the gzip utility, and it is not affected by how the gzip file is made. The contents of the gzip file cannot direct the decompressed data to some other directory. (If it could, that would be a security issue.)

It is possible to store a file name in the gzip header, in which case `gzip -N whatever.gz` will decompress to the name in the header as opposed to `whatever`. However it will be a file in the current directory using just the base name in the header. Any path information in the file name in the gzip header is ignored.